How to make height and width for layer same as stage in vue-konva
I can't seem to find a straight forward answer on this. I'm using Konva with Vue and i want the layer to be the same width and height as the stage.
I tried to change the layer width with width: variable.width which would be the same value i use on stage, i get a warning saying i have to use stage.width().

You don't need to set width/height of the layer. Its size is automatically follows stage size.
